# Android save and get objects offline

Tags: java, android

For my application I have the following structure (simplified)

```
models
-->GameType1Model : GameType
-->GameType2Model : GameType
-->Game
   //has object : ArrayList<GameType> mGanetypes

abstractclasses
-->GameType

activitys
-->MainActivity
-->Gametype1
-->Gametype2
-->PlayGame
      // has method : start(Game)
```

A game can contain multiple gameType models. A game can be started in the playGame activity with start(Game) and uses a game object to know which GameType activitys to start. The gameTypeModels contains different values like int score, ArrayList etc.

An application can have multiple games (in a list).

My goal is to save a game so the user is able to continue it after a reboot of his mobile. If i want to do this this means I have to be able to update the gameTypeModels when the game is played and save the Game model that contains the gameTypeModel.

**My thoughts**

I need to load the Games in the MainActivity so Im able to select a game.

I need to be able to edit the data in every GameType.

How should I save my data so it will be easy to continu a game and save the data of a specific GameType in a game ?

*The game can be played offline so I have to use localdata/storage*

Comment: How about in a database?  You can use an ORM to make it easier.

Comment: @nasch what database would you suggest for offline usage ?

Comment: Sqlite.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

### Java code to save Object offline (Serialization)

**serialStore.java**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class serialStore {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        app a = new app();
        a.name = "example text to store.";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\abc.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(a);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Serializarion done and data saved in file.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class app implements java.io.Serializable {
    public String name;
}
```